# How many 6-letter arrangements (without repetitions) of A, B, C, D, E, F are there in which A is just before B and C is just after B?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So i was given this question

How many 6-letter arrangements (without repetitions) of A, B, C, D,
E, F are there in which A is just before B and C is just after B?

What throws me off is how to make sure A is just before B and C is just after B?

My guess was $6!/3$ Because the three conditions but i'm really lost by this

Comment: Tie them together in that order to make a "superletter."

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you explain what you mean by tie them together?

Comment: Your question has been answered by joedoe8595.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, your condition implies that the sequence ABC is fixed? In that case, I guess you could model the question by asking for permutations of ABC, D, E, F of which there are 4!.

Comment: But how does that satisfy the condition where there should be no repetitions. Wouldn't there be in that case?

Comment: Let's look at a shorter example and omit the F here. Your permutations in this case are:
ABC D E, ABC E D, E ABC D, E D ABC, D ABC E, D E ABC
Those are exactly 3!=6 permutations, as you'd expect for 3 items, without repetitions. But ABC D E is just another way of expressing A B C D E which is a permutation of A, B, C, D, E that fullfils your condition.

Comment: Oh thank you a lot for the explanation